# Thrift bin file large size after compile

Tags: docker, g++, thrift, alpine-linux

I have a problem with compilation Thrift in docker container with alpine 3.8

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        libstdc++ \
        libgcc \
        libevent \
        composer \
        tar \
        git \
        bash \
        nginx

RUN  apk add --update --no-cache php7-dev boost-dev  autoconf  openssl-dev  automake make libtool bison flex  g++  && \
     cd /tmp && wget https://github.com/apache/thrift/archive/0.11.0.zip -O thrift.zip  && unzip thrift.zip && cd thrift-0.11.0 && \
     ./bootstrap.sh && ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl --without-ruby --disable-tests --without-php_extension --without-python --without-haskell --without-java --without-perl --without-php --without-py3 --without-erlang && make && make install && \
     cd /tmp/thrift-0.11.0/lib/php/src/ext/thrift_protocol && phpize && ./configure && make && \
     echo 'extension=thrift_protocol.so' >> /etc/php7/conf.d/thrift_protocol.ini && \
     apk del --update --no-cache  php7-dev boost-dev  autoconf openssl-dev   automake make libtool bison flex  g++  && \
     rm -rf /tmp/*
```

after compile bin file has size around 50MB

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      55566368 Sep  5 10:05 thrift
```

for example bin file after compile on Mac OSX

```
 4.2M Sep  4 17:37 thrift
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `configure && make` will cause Thrift to be built with debug symbols, which is the major reason for binary bloating.

For building a more compact and optimized `thrift` binary, replace:

`configure`

With:

`configure CFLAGS="-s -O2" CXXFLAGS="-s -O2"`

The `-s` compiler option will cause debug information to be stripped away from generated objects.
The `-O2` compiler option will enable common compiler optimizations, which should improve `thrift` performance considerably.

More information:

- https://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: thanks so much, it works `4274320 Sep 13 08:48 thrift`